# Webdriver search within element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In Telerik it’s possible to search elements within an element that was already found. E.g. I found an ul, that has some elements li. After that I can invoke find() directly from the element.

Is there such possibility using the WebDriver Java?

Answer (score 3):

In WebDriver the usual way of finding an element on the page is;

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath query here"));
```

The `findElement` method is provided by [`SearchContext`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html) inferface, which [`WebElement`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) also extends. This means you can call `findElement` on any element found by a previous search;

```
WebElement child = element.findElement(By.xpath("another xpath query"));
```

Comment: There's no better answer than this. Also reminding the fact that you could store all elements with a similar locator in a List<WebElement>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use
`List<WebElement> = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ul li"));`

Your list contains all li elements who are in the ul.